# d3: skipping lines when reading in csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to read in a csv file with D3 and I'm a little stuck. The way my csv file is formatted is that the first line is a merged cell containing a year then the next line will contain the data descriptions (name, age etc).

Currently I have the following:

```
var resourceList = [{description: "All Yearly Data",
                            name: "yearlyData",
                            path: "data.csv"};

d3.csv(resourceInfo.path, function(error, d) {
    theData.resources[resourceInfo.name].processed = true;
    theData.resources[resourceInfo.name].error = error;
    theData.resources[resourceInfo.name].data = d;
    theData.numProcessed += 1;      
});
```

This reads the first line in as the data descriptions and then the following lines as actual data. What I want to do is have an multidimensional array which I could go through by year. Is it possible to skip lines while parsing to make sure I can manage that or no?

Thanks!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090642/d3-ignore-certain-row-in-csv) should help.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff What I don't think I'm getting is inside of the inner function where I do theData.resources[resourceInfo.name].data = d, If outside I create an array and I push d, the array never holds anything upon the completion of the function...

Comment: `d3.csv` is asynchronous -- the code hasn't executed when the function returns.

Comment: So how can I access a specific line of the csv file at any point?

Comment: Once the data has loaded, you just need to index into the array of lines passed to the callback.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Could you give an example? Sorry. I'm fairly new at this

Comment: In your code, `d[9]` to get the data from the 10th line.

Answer (score 0):

one way of getting at this would be to use filter:

```
d3.csv(resourceInfo.path, function(error, d) {
    var newData = d.filter(function(obs) { return INSERT YOUR FILTER CONDITION HERE;}); 
    ...
```

see also:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter