# Convert data file to .csv or .json for d3.js plotting

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Data files commonly used in `gnuplot` are generally of this kind:

```
  # This is my input

###a              b               c                 d        ---etc---
a030067o.fits  2457542.734730    60.00  1.2690   -0.174    0.003    9.871737    
a030068o.fits   ????????????      60.00  1.2650   -1.197    1.682    9.869020   
  a030069o.fits  2457542.736397    60.00     1.2610   -1.320   -0.429    9.865766     
a030070o.fits  2457542.737242  60.00  1.2570   -0.503   -0.192    9.867632   


a030071o.fits  2457542.738075    60.00  1.2530    0.370    0.424    9.868780   
a030072o.fits  2457542.738920     60.00  1.2490   -0.000   -0.003    9.869078    
a030073o.fits  2457542.739753    60.00  1.2450   -1.491    0.117    9.868382     


# Third Dataset
a030074o.fits  2457542.740598    60.00  1.2410   -1.413    0.811    9.867624   
a030075o.fits  2457542.741432    60.00  1.2370    0.363    1.411    9.866734   
  a030076o.fits  2457542.742277    60.00  1.2340   -0.868   -0.115    9.861761    
a030077o.fits  2457542.743110    60.00  1.2300   -0.411    0.206    9.865149
```

Basically,

- groups of lines separated by two new lines;
- with arbitrary leading/trailing/middle spaces or tabs between columns;
- with undefined (`???`) fields;
- and with comments times to times.

This is very common in science, where `gnuplot` is very used.

Unfortunately, this format is awful if I want to produce **web-based graphs with `d3.js`**

In the case it has just a header line made like that

```
###a b c    d  e     f
```

I am able to parse it with

```
d3.text("file.dat", function (error,data){ 

    data=data.replace(/[ \t\r]+/g,',');
    var data = d3.csvParse(data)

});
```

but I cannot use it without the header line.

Neither this works ([read csv/tsv with no header line in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870265/read-csv-tsv-with-no-header-line-in-d3)):

```
data=data.replace(/[ \t\r]+/g,',');                     
data = d3.csvParseRows(data).map(function(row) {        
    return row.map(function(value) {                    
        return +value;                                  
    });                                                 
});
```

Neither this ([D3: ignore certain row in .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090642/d3-ignore-certain-row-in-csv)):

```
d3.request("pianeta-ascii.dat").get(function (error,request) {             

    var dirtyCSV = request.responseText;   \s+(?=\s)                       
    dirtyCSV=dirtyCSV.replace(/\s/g,',');                                  
    var cleanCSV = dirtyCSV.split('\n').slice(1).join('\n');               
    var data = d3.csvParseRows(cleanCSV);                      

});
```

How can I make it work skipping comments and separating data groups?

I would like at least the javascript version of

```
 cat file.dat | grep -v "\#" |sed '/^\s*$/d' |awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5}'
```

and, if it possible, a way to separate the data groups in `d3`

Comment: Facing the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution to convert the gnuplot data ?

Comment: No, I didn't find anything

Comment: Bump? Still nothing?

Comment: so, strictly speaking this has "nothing" to do with gnuplot at all. This is just a text format which gnuplot and other programs can easily handle. Basically, you are looking for JavaScript code of a text conversion routine.

Comment: @theozh for that reason I labeled the question "Convert data file to..."