# Can't update users disconnected with socket.io

Tags: javascript, sockets

I can't update users list when a user is disconnected, only updates when a user is connected, what's the problem on my code?. 
If i have user A, B, C and C leaves the room the list still with the users A, B , C and must be just A and B.

SERVER

```
var app = require('express')();
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.use(express.static('./public'));
var users = [];
var nicks = new Array();

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });


    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('adduser', function (user) {
        socket.user = user;
        users.push(user);
        updateClients();
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
            if(users[i] == socket.user) {
                   delete users[users[i]];
            }
        }
        updateClients(); 
    });

    function updateClients() {
        io.sockets.emit('update', users);
    }

});










    http.listen(3000, function(){
      console.log('listening on *:3000');
    });
```

CLIENT

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

     var socket = io();



     socket.on('connect', function (){
            socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
        });

        var userList = [];

        socket.on('update', function (users){
            userList = users;

                $( "h1" ).remove();
            for(var i=0; i<userList.length; i++) {

             $('#wrap').append("<h1>" + userList[i] + "</h1>"); 
            }
        });

        });
```

Comment: `delete users[users[i]]` -> `users.splice(i, 1)`

Comment: @Andreas that works perfectly!!! so many thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove element from an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003815/how-to-remove-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)