# JavaScript delete keeps "empty" in Object

Tags: javascript

Trying to delete elements from object using `delete` , but while the value is gone, there's still "empty" in the object. as show in the image:

[image]

which causing unwanted behviour in a following iteration:

```
for (const [key, value] of ids.entries()) {
    if (Object.values(this.widget_ids).indexOf(value) >= 0) {
        delete ids[key]
    }
}
```

now, i can't use `pop` or `shift` since . i need the option to remove by key, any idea how can i delete and remove this empty slot? or even better, remove while not having do deal with it at all?

Comment: I think you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003815/how-to-remove-element-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: share your full code ?

Comment: You are using an array, thats why the index you delete keeps an empty value. Use an object instead, look at my example: https://image.prntscr.com/image/HmwM_SViSAuoO9qNTbSZEQ.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), which allows to delete at a given index an amount of elements.

[`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) deletes the element and leaves a sparse array at this index, but it does not changes the lenght of the array.

```js
var ids = [322, 324, 435];

ids.splice(0, 1);
//         ^     index
//            ^  count of elements to delete

console.log(ids);
```

Comment: just an add on, as OP seems to want to delete by id: use `indexOf(key)` in the splice function....

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `delete` is that it deletes the object property, but will not reindex the array or update its length. This makes it appears as if it is `undefined` or empty.

`splice(start, deleteCount)` removes the element from the array:

```js
var ids = [322, 324, 435];
ids.splice(ids.indexOf(322), ids.indexOf(322) + 1);
console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use splice instead of delete, it just set `undefined`

```js
var ids = [1,2,3];
console.log(ids);
ids.splice(1,1);
console.log(ids);
```