# How to delete an array from object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an object of type : [ {name : 'xxx' , price: '555', quantity : '2' } , {...} ] and so one.
I got a class

```
 getCartItems() {
        let items = localStorage.getItem('item');
        items = JSON.parse(items);
        return items;
    }
```

where i get this array.
Now i am getting index of the array, for example 0 , it should remove first array from object.
but when i do .remove, or other, it does not work. this.getCartItems()[index].remove or other does not work. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean remove the first element? if so try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003825/1429439

Comment: I mean to remove the whole first array... Does not work :(

Comment: Remove the first array? You mean remove the first _element from the array_?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003815/how-to-remove-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: is it remove object from array ?

Comment: Sorry for my english, i am not a native speaker. 
My initial array is [ {name : 'xxx' , price: '555', quantity : '2' } , {name : 'x2' , price: '23' , quantity: '543'},  {name : 'x3' , price: '26' , quantity: '5123'}] 

I need to delete first object, the array would look like:
 [{name : 'x2' , price: '23' , quantity: '543'},  {name : 'x3' , price: '26' , quantity: '5123'}]

Comment: this.getCartItems()[toRemoveID] = this.getCartItems()[toRemoveID].slice(toRemoveID, 1); 
i tried this one, however i get Uncaught TypeError: this.getCartItems(...)[toRemoveID].slice is not a function

Comment: getCartItems() returns an array of object?

Comment: yes, it does return

Comment: Man, few people around here are native English speakers :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are mutating the object after you parse it and you never save it back.

You have to save the mutated object inside of your localStorage to make your removal of the first item persistant.

Look at the following example :

```js
const localStorage = {
  items: {
    item: JSON.stringify([{
      name: 'xxx',
      price: '555',
      quantity: '2',
    }, {
      name: 'yyy',
      price: '666',
      quantity: '5',
    }, {
      name: 'zzz',
      price: '777',
      quantity: '6',
    }]),
  },

  getItem: str => localStorage.items[str],

  setItem: (str, value) => {
    localStorage.items[str] = value;
  },
};

function getCartItems() {
  const items = localStorage.getItem('item');

  const parsedItems = JSON.parse(items);

  // We remove the first element
  const item = parsedItems.splice(0, 1);

  // We save the value
  localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(parsedItems));

  return item;
}


console.log('First call ---');
console.log(getCartItems());
console.log('');
console.log('Second call ---');
console.log(getCartItems());
console.log('');
console.log('Third call ---');
console.log(getCartItems());
```

Comment: I have a method removeCart where i am clicking an <a id=..> which gives the index of the object in array, when i click removeCard i am sending that index to remove that from object... But... it does not work (

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` to get required items. In the following updated will not have earlier 0 index item. Now, the `updated` array you may want to set in localStorage again if required.

```
const items = getCartItems();
const indexToRemove = 0;

const updated = items.filter((,index) => index !== indexToRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array method `filter` to remove the object from array. This can look something like this:

```
     getCartItems() {
        let items = localStorage.getItem('item');
        items = JSON.parse(items);
        return items;
    }
    removeCart(){
    return id; // the id that you will have from your a tag
    }
const updatedItems = this.getCartItems().filter((item,index) => index !== this.removeCart()); // in updated items you will find your filtered out array of object
```