# how do i remove item from inside object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects like

```
 let = cartItem =
   {
    "_id": "6075a0ddf88a6035001376d0",
    "buyerId": "603e808bab11752d38c463cb",
    "buyerEmail": "hassaanather00@gmail.com",
    "buyerName": "Muhammad  Hassaan Ather",
    "products": [
          {
              "_id": "6075a9afb5335c2e94b29c1b",
              "productId": "606ddc2a4b7adbd74c703746",
              "quantity": 4,
              "productTitle": "New",
              "productSelectedFile": "URL",
              "productPrice": 10000
          },
          {
              "_id": "6075abf8b5335c2e94b29c1c",
              "productId": "605df90844bf6e0264544b77",
              "quantity": 1,
              "productTitle": "Wooden",
              "productSelectedFile":             
              "anyUrl",
              "productPrice": 100000
          }
        ],

      }
```

Now i want to remove one of the **PRODUCT** in the **cartItem** object. I have tried this method but after updating it also make a mess to the original **CARTITEM**.

```
  let newCart = cartItems.products.filter((item) => item.productId !== id);
```

In the end the original cartItem object is also not showing anything.

Waht i want is to remove one product from products array and send back the remaining array.

Comment: Array.filter() does NOT edit the original array, so the issue with "making a mess to the original CARTITEM" is a mystery to me.
However you might wanna see this answer how to remove elements from js arrays.
Just find the index and then use splice:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003815/how-to-remove-element-from-an-array-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1

Beware as Array.splice() will modify the original array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not too far off. Your initial solution only returns the new array products and not your whole object. You just need to add another line of code to add the new array of products into a new object of cartItems.

```js
let newCartItemProducts = cartItems.products.filter((item) => item.productId !== id);
let newCartItems = {...cartItems, products: newCartItemProducts}
```

Comment: in the end, I am proud that i was not too far off :). Thanks a lot that worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let = cartItem =
   {
    "_id": "6075a0ddf88a6035001376d0",
    "buyerId": "603e808bab11752d38c463cb",
    "buyerEmail": "hassaanather00@gmail.com",
    "buyerName": "Muhammad  Hassaan Ather",
    "products": [
          {
              "_id": "6075a9afb5335c2e94b29c1b",
              "productId": "606ddc2a4b7adbd74c703746",
              "quantity": 4,
              "productTitle": "New",
              "productSelectedFile": "URL",
              "productPrice": 10000
          },
          {
              "_id": "6075abf8b5335c2e94b29c1c",
              "productId": "605df90844bf6e0264544b77",
              "quantity": 1,
              "productTitle": "Wooden",
              "productSelectedFile":             
              "anyUrl",
              "productPrice": 100000
          }
        ]
}
      
//delete 6075abf8b5335c2e94b29c1c

for (var i = 0; i < cartItem["products"].length; i++) {
  if (cartItem["products"][i]["_id"] == "6075abf8b5335c2e94b29c1c") {
    cartItem["products"].splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(cartItem);
```

Comment: Except that this does something different: if `cartItems` is state, this modifies it directly.

Comment: Thanks. solution worked well but as i am woring in REACTJS so the component was not rendering after updating the state. I tried "Kevin Eaten" answer below that worked best.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
removeProduct(id){
   let index = cartItem.products.findIndex((product: any) => product._id === id);
   if (index != -1) cartItem.products.splice(index,1);
   return cartItem.products;
}
```

It will remove a product with specified `id` from the `products` of the `cartItem` and it will return the remaining `products`.

Comment: this removes everything from the array. Kevin's solution worked for me. thanks!